# How can i check if a string value is nil ("") in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I came across an issue but i cant find a solution to it.

I currently have this code:

```
Image.network(
  stream['stream_icon'] != "" ? stream['stream_icon'] : 'missingicon.jpg',
  width: 100,
  height: 150,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object error, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
    print('Error loading image: $error');
    print('Stack trace: $stackTrace');

    return Image.network(
      'missingicon.jpg',
      width: 100,
      height: 150,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    );
  },
),
```

So what this code does (With allot more above it) is it sends a api request to a domain. Which then returns a value. For example: "stream_icon": "perfectworkingimage.jpg",

So that works and displays well withing the app. But there is one value on the site: "stream_icon": "", Which makes the app crash since it cant reach the image nor display it on the screen. How can i check if a value of a string is empty and if it is, trow the missingicon.jpg?

Here is the error:

```
Error: HTTP request failed, statusCode: 400, https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 297:3       throw_
packages/flutter/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart 146:11                      <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 550:37  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 555:39  dcall
```

I tried using multiple methods such as checking if the value was nil, which cant be done because there is a string "". So its always available. And asked chatGPT but didnt help out any better (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string can be either empty or null, you can declare a little helper function

```
 bool isNullOrEmpty(String? str){
     return (str ?? "").isEmpty;
 }
```

Then you can use it on your component

```
isNullOrEmpty(stream['stream_icon']) ? 'missingicon.jpg' : stream['stream_icon'],
...
```

resources:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-string-is-empty-or-not-in-dart/

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for helping me. Is it right that this solution does not work for webview? On my iPad it succesfully replaces the image, but the webview freezes for a few seconds and then reloads the whole app.

Again, thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jesper2908 Its strange, this uses dart coalescing operator, it should work on all environments. Maybe there is some other issue, like a library that you are using that is not compatible with web view. I don't thing this is the issue. Maybe check the logs to see if there is an error. Just in case I put here some alternatives. Instead of `return (str ?? "").isEmpty;` you can use `return (str ?? "").length==0;` or maybe `return str == null || str.isEmpty;` or finally `return str == null || str.length == 0;`. All of them should produce the same result